# Fail in Importing Projects from Team Foundation Server into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I try to import my project from Team Foundation Serverinto eclipse.
I used this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568707.aspx
I tried to remove my old workspaces, it also doesn`t help.
The error I get is "Error importing projects: 0".
Also when I try to import from Source Control I fail to set local folder.

Thank you for any help:)

Comment: This is the error I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ykxbldem24r6ql/importError.jpg

Comment: My solution: I had Visual Studio 2012 installed with Team Foundation Server. I extracted the project using TFS of  Visual Studio 2012. After that I just imported the project into my eclipse work-space.